# Django TextField always is required, despite blank=True,Null=True

Tags: python, django, web, backend

I am having trouble with a field that seems to always want to be required despite my best wishes. My 'word_search' text field is always requesting data to be input but I have been trying to make sure the options allow for a blank.

my model is this. You can see the blank=True,Null=True options

```
class IAV(models.Model):

  z_score = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 4,decimal_places=4)
  screens = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  flu_proteins = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
  Key_word = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
  sess = models.ForeignKey(Sess_IAV,default=None)
```

my view is this

```
def new_IAV(request):

  if request.method == "POST":
    form = IAVForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
      sess_ = Sess_IAV.objects.create()
      form.save(
          for_page=sess_,
          z_score = form.cleaned_data("z_score"),
          screens = form.cleaned_data("screens"),
          flu_proteins = form.cleaned_data("flu_proteins"),
          Key_word = form.cleaned_data("key_word"),
          )
      return redirect(sess_)
    else:
      print(form.errors)
  else:
    url=reverse('IAV_home')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

My form is this. you can see the required=False attribute.

```
class IAVForm(forms.models.ModelForm):

  z_score = forms.DecimalField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','value':'0.0',}))

  screens = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','value':'0',}))

  flu_proteins = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','value':'0',}))

  key_word = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control','rows':1,'cols':10,'placeholder':'keword values','required':'False'}))


  class Meta:
    model=IAV
    fields=('z_score','screens','flu_proteins','key_word')

  def save(self,for_page,z_score,screens,flu_proteins,key_word):
    self.instance.sess = for_page
    self.instance.z_score = z_score
    self.instance.screens = screens
    self.instance.flu_proteins = flu_proteins
    self.instance.key_word = key_word
    return super().save()
```

I am not sure how this field is not allowed to be left blank considering the model has the 'blank=True, null=True' options present.

Also the widget says that it isn't reqired.

[image: This is what shows up]

Comment: Did you add the `null=True` _after_ a migration ?

Comment: In the form, the field is called 'key_word' but in the model it's called 'word_serach'. Why?

Comment: @onyeka yes I have changed this. The problem persists.

Comment: @karthikr I have done migrations after and the change is reflected in my migration files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
class IAVForm(forms.ModelForm):
  z_score = forms.DecimalField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','value':'0.0',}))
  screens = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','value':'0',}))
  flu_proteins = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','value':'0',}))
  key_word = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control','rows':1,'cols':10,'placeholder':'keword values'}))
```

To begin, you can just make the class `(forms.ModelForm).` Additionally, you had `required=False` inside of quotes and as an attribute. Remove the quotes and put it before the attributes of the widget.

See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(IAVForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.fields["key_word"].required = False
```

Also I noticed that `key_word` is not in your model fields!

Comment: Thanks @Othman for the response! I tried what you had said and the problem persists. I have added an image of what is showing up

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the required property completely from the field attributes. `Required="True/False"` is not valid. If you want to disable it you have to remove it completely, [per the W3C Specs](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute) and [this article](http://blog.grayghostvisuals.com/html/using-html-required-attribute/).

Comment: Or probably set it to `required="required"` as it's another way to do it as per the links?